# Angular how to sort date objects of array?

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to order an array which includes Date objects inside.

Here my array `Appointment[]` is below(contains 3 objects)

```
0: {id: 36, appointmentDate: "2019-12-27T10:28:15"}
1: {id: 57, appointmentDate: "2020-01-03T08:29:25"}
2: {id: 58, appointmentDate: "2020-01-15T15:45:19"}
```

Here's the method I tried to implement but didn't work it says
 `a.appointmentDate.getTime is not a function`

```
if(param === 'a'){
      return value.sort((a, b) => { return a.appointmentDate.getTime() - b.appointmentDate.getTime() });
}
```

Here also another approach didn't work either below says

`The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type`

```
  if(param === 'a'){
  return value.sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a.appointmentDate) - new Date(b.appointmentDate});
    }
```

Comment: Directly use string sorting: `a.appointmentDate.localeCompare(b.appointmentDate)`. If you want to use Date constructor add `+` in front of  the date objects: `+new Date(a.appointmentDate)`. Typescript doesn't like subtracting dates and type coercion

Comment: The first one throws an error because `appointmentDate` is a string and not a `Date`. The second error is from TypeScript because it doesn't allow the `-` operation on `Date` objects. Just check the documentation for `Date` if there is a method/property that returns a numerical representation of the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your two efforts:

```
if(param === 'a'){
  return value.sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a.appointmentDate).getTime() - new Date(b.appointmentDate).getTime() })
}
```